# Stack overflow when opening menu with ApplicationCommands in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, stack-overflow, command

When I add an ApplicationCommands command to a MenuItem in my file menu, no matter via XAML or via code, when I open the menu the application crashes in a stack overflow, with absolutely no details about the problem. When I remove the Command, the problem also disappears. It doesn't matter which ApplicationCommand I use.

Part of the call stack:

- WindowsBase.dll!MS.Utility.ArrayItemList.ArrayItemList(int
  size) + 0x20 bytes
- WindowsBase.dll!MS.Utility.FrugalStructList.Capacity.set(int
  value) + 0x6a bytes
- WindowsBase.dll!MS.Utility.FrugalStructList.FrugalStructList(int
  size) + 0x9 bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.EventRoute(System.Windows.RoutedEvent
  routedEvent) + 0x35 bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRouteFactory.FetchObject(System.Windows.RoutedEvent
  routedEvent) + 0x31 bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject
  sender =
  {System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox},
  System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args =
  {System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs}) + 0x3f bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs
  args =
  {System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs},
  bool trusted) + 0x35 bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CriticalCanExecuteWrapper(object
  parameter,
  System.Windows.IInputElement target,
  bool trusted,
  System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs
  args) + 0x80 bytes
  PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CanExecuteImpl(object
  parameter = null,
  System.Windows.IInputElement target =
  {System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox},
  bool trusted = false, out bool
  continueRouting = false) + 0x70
  bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CriticalCanExecute(object
  parameter,
  System.Windows.IInputElement target,
  bool trusted, out bool
  continueRouting) + 0x3a bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.TransferEvent(System.Windows.IInputElement
  newSource,
  System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs
  e =
  {System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs}) + 0x52 bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnCanExecute(object
  sender,
  System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs
  e) + 0x8c bytes
  PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnCanExecuteThunk(object
  sender,
  System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs
  e) + 0x44 bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate
  genericHandler, object target) + 0x41
  bytes
  PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate
  handler, object target) + 0x27 bytes 
  PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object
  target,
  System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs
  routedEventArgs) + 0x3e bytes
  PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object
  source =
  {System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox},
  System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args =
  {System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs},
  bool reRaised = false) + 0x1bf bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject
  sender =
  {System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox},
  System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args = + 0x79 bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs
  args =
  {System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs},
  bool trusted) + 0x35 bytes
- PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CriticalCanExecuteWrapper(object
  parameter,
  System.Windows.IInputElement target,
  bool trusted,
  System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs
  args) + 0x80 bytes

It looks like the application is stuck in an endless loop. Is this my fault (and what am I doing wrong) or a bug in .NET 3.5?

I use this code:

```
MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
mi.Command = ApplicationCommands.Open;
FileMenu.Items.Add(mi);
```

It doesn't matter wheter I create the menuItem via code or in XAML, and like I said setting the Command also doesn't matter where. The problem also occurs when using MediaCommands, so I guess for all Commands in general.

The RichTextBox code:

```
//configure richtextbox
sb = new RichTextBox();
sb.Margin = new Thickness(-3);
sb.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
sb.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
sb.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
///TODO: get font from preferences.
FontFamilyConverter ffc = new FontFamilyConverter();
sb.FontFamily = (FontFamily)ffc.ConvertFromString("Lucida Sans Unicode");
sb.FontSize = 13;
sb.AcceptsReturn = true; sb.AcceptsTab = true;
sb.AllowDrop = true; sb.IsDocumentEnabled = false;
sb.Padding = new Thickness(5);

//markup styles
Style s = new Style(typeof(Paragraph));
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(Paragraph.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0)));
sb.Resources.Add(typeof(Paragraph), s);

this.AddChild(sb);
```

The RichTextBox is added in the constructor of a control that is derived from TabItem.

Comment: Where is this code located? What method is it in?

Comment: The code is in the constructor of the window. It doesn't matter whether I set the Command before the MenuItem is added to the Menu or after, I tried both.

Comment: For me it's strange to see System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox as sender in that stack trace.

Comment: I do have a RichTextBox in my window, is this related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was adding my RichTextBox to a focus group. I removed that and now it works. Altough I still can't get the keyboard focus in the RichTextBox at startup. (Tried Keyboard.Focus(sb), sb.Focus(), sb.Document.Focus(), Keyboard.Focus(sb.Document), FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, sb), ect...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is your fault and not a bug in 3.5 (hey, you asked).  Now to find your bug...

From the stack trace, there are a lot of CanExecute events, and they seem to be associated with a RichTextBox.  Do you have any CanExecute logic in your code? Honestly, we need more code in order to help effectively.

Also, an endless loop and stack overflow are different. Does your program ever blow up with the SO exception or does it just keep running forever?

Comment: No, just the StackOverflow error. I don't have any CanExecute logic in my code. (I added the RichTextbox code to my question).

Comment: You must have to some sort of recursive/circular call in there. Do you have any event handlers doing some logic they shouldn't be?

Comment: I did some other test, and it turns out that not all commands return error... ApplicationCommands.Undo doens't.